# ACF - set / update default value of field based on other field

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

So I have a repeater field with a bunch of subfields. Because of certain reasons I need get value of one field (called: data) and place it into second field (called: month_year). Unfortunately my current code doesn't work. It returns no value / do not replicate any value from field data. That's why the `month_year` field is blank.

Here is it:

```
function my_acf_load_field( $field ) {
    $current_date = get_sub_field('data');
    $trimmed = substr($current_date, -7);
    $field['default_value'] = $trimmed;
    $field['disabled'] = 1;
    return $field;  
}
add_filter('acf/load_field/name=month_year', 'my_acf_load_field');
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: Good question. "Seems not to work" is a very broad description

Comment: `get_sub_field()` doesn't magically grab the right parent repeater field. This is supposed to work in a context after `the_row()` was called in a loop. You cannot use it here. The question is: what does data contain and what reason are you cutting off the last 7 characters? Maybe, there is an even simpler solution.

Comment: @Damocles - ok so giving you a bigger picture - the repeater field is called: workshops. User is providing via this field number of specific parameters including place (fieldname: locations), date (fieldname: data)  and price. New subfield (month_year) is suppose to take value from data field and trim it. Why trim? because values from "data" field looks like that: 03.04.2020, 10-20.01.2020 etc. There is no pattern in it. Because I need to have a month+year value attached to the object I thought the easiest way is to create new field (month_year) and just trim value of data field.